# Volley Could not validate certificate

Tags: android, android-volley

I am using Volley for a month now,
and i just encounter this error.

```
01-28 01:52:48.973 17167-17167/? E/RESPONSE ERROR: com.android.volley.NoConnectionError: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: com.android.org.bouncycastle.jce.exception.ExtCertPathValidatorException: Could not validate certificate: Certificate expired at Sun Jan 01 07:59:59 GMT+08:00 2017 (compared to Sat Jan 28 01:52:48 GMT+08:00 2017)
```

Before this happened.
I am using my app for google api.
I have more than 1k Request for 1Day.

Comment: Your device time seems to be 1 year in the future.

Comment: ohh thank you. didn't notice that. Thanks!